# How can I prepend to PATH while running Ansible's pip module?

Tags: automation, ansible

I'm attempting to install psycopg2 into a Python virtualenv with Ansible's `pip` module, but I need to prepend an entry to PATH for it to build correctly (it needs to know the path to the directory containing `pg_config`).  I see that I can pass `environment` to the `pip` module, but I'm unsure of how to prepend rather than overwrite `PATH`.

Here I'm attempting to prepend the path with the necessary directory, but it overwrites the virtualenv `PATH` and fails:

```
- pip:
    name: psycopg2
    virtualenv: /path/to/my/venv
  environment:
    PATH: /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you are using Ansible 1.4 or later (which I recommend) you can access the **remote** `PATH` env variable:

```
- pip: name=psycopg2 virtualenv=/path/to/my/venv
  environment:
    PATH: /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}
```

If instead you are interested in the `PATH` env var of the **local client** running the Ansible scripts (instead of the targeted *server*), then you want to do the following:

```
- pip: name=psycopg2 virtualenv=/path/to/my/venv
  environment:
    # This only makes sense if your client and server are homogeneous, that is,
    # they have the same PATHs.
    PATH: /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin:{{ lookup('env', 'PATH') }}
```

Comment: The `ansible_env.PATH` option was what I needed — worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this takes the PATH of the workstation, not the server!

Comment: If you need to prepend `~/bin`, use `PATH: "{{ansible_env.HOME}}/bin:{{ansible_env.PATH}}"`. If you instead use `PATH: "~/bin:{{ansible_env.PATH}}"`, then some programs (such as Python's `shutil.which`) are unable to use that component.

Comment: Be also aware that `ansible_env` refers to the environment of the SSH user, not the `sudo` environment. `ansible_env.USER` may therefore result in `root` rather than an unprivileged user.